# IIS Authorization Rules multiple Groups levels web.config

Tags: iis, iis-10

I am currently using the following in my IIS 10 web.config to limit access to my website.
We have planed to add another group here to give access to some parts of the website to other users.

My questions is what is best approach here?

```
<security>
     <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="WebSuperUsers" />
     </authorization>
  </security>
```

New group needs to have access to index file in root and some other pages located under different folders.

Comment: you could set allow rule for everyone and set deny rule where you don't want other users to access the folder or file. you could also set the web.config file for the specif folder.